# Recover React Js files using a build's static folder

Tags: reactjs, tsx

A while ago I made a project in React Js. When finished, I generated a build using "npm build" and uploaded these static files to a shared hosting.

Some time later, I needed to change this project and I discovered that I had lost all the original files on my computer, leaving only the build files.

Is there a way to recover these lost original files by "reverse" these static build files?

I saw that inside the /static/js/ folder there are several files with the extension "randomname.chuck.js".

Is there a way to use them to rebuild my original files?

Any help is welcome!